# Actual method being called instead of stub'd version

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I am running a Chef spec unit test using the command below. The relevant code is shown further below. I expected some_test_data to be used in the unit test instead of method_name actually getting called. But what is  happening is that the stub is not used. Instead method_name does actually get called, which in this case is not appropriate in the unit test. What am I mis-understanding or doing wrong here? Thank you.

rspec spec/unit/mytest_spec.rb

```
# Code from Chef Spec mytest_spec.rb unit test
allow(ClassName).to receive(:method_name).and_return(some_test_data)

# Code unit test is testing
my_variable = method_name(node)

# Method that gets called above
def self.method_name(node)
  # Do something
end
```

Comment: The code is too much pseudo. To the point that it's not clear what is expected to happen, what happens instead and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you're passing a parameter to `method_name` but in the stubbed method, you're not stubbing out the parameters. That is why the stubbed method doesn't get called when you run the tests.

It should be

```
allow(ClassName).to receive(:method_name).with('argument').and_return(some_test_data)
```

[I am not sure about the following because you didn't post the actual code.
You can ignore it if my assumption is wrong]

You're testing a class method, but you're not calling it on the class. ie.

Shouldn't `my_variable = method_name(node)` be `my_variable = Classname.method_name(node)` ?

For more, see https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-99/docs/method-stubs and https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-2/docs/setting-constraints/matching-arguments

Comment: Not expecting parameters with `.with` will not prevent the stubbing.

Comment: Thank you very much Arun. This is now working. I don't need this to be a class method, so have removed "self." from "def self.method_name(node)", after which this now works.

Comment: @Owen, Glad that it helped.